# Hotlinking Unsplash images results in broken image

Tags: html, image, hotlinking

Unsplash prefers that users of their API hotlink images from urls that they provide.

Seems almost silly to be asking this, but for some reason this simple piece of code is not working when trying to hotlink an image, whose url I grab from the Unsplash API:

```
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484995342839-a9eb42974616?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=3c7ad78ab40416cdfae002147d8b8003">
```

This url comes is found in their GET photo response under: `photo.urls.small`

It is probably a minor oversight on my part, anyone see my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was an extension called Privacy badger on Chrome that is blacklisting the link.

Answer (score 0):

When I test the code it works. Possibly a cache issue?

```
<img src="//images.unsplash.com/photo-1484995342839-a9eb42974616?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=3c7ad78ab40416cdfae002147d8b8003">
```

Comment: Figured it out - Privacy Badger plugin is blacklisting it. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the parameter in that image URL. Do try by eliminating the parameters after "?" and just pass the remaining URL as below:

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484995342839-a9eb42974616